# How can I show the latest post untrimmed and trim the rest?

Tags: php, trim

I would like to have the latest post show full rather than trim it, but then the other posts be trimmed.  I am unsure how to do so, so here I am!
Here's some code!

```
<div id="news">
    <?php

    $query=mysql_query("SELECT NewsID, Title, Content, Author, 
                        date_format(Date, '%m/%d/%y') AS Date
                        FROM news ORDER BY NewsID DESC LIMIT 2");

    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
        echo "<div class=\"news_item\">
                <div class=\"title\">
                    <a href=\"article.php?newsID=$row[NewsID]\">$row[Title]</a>
                </div>
                <div class=\"date\">
                    Posted: $row[Date] by $row[Author]
                </div>
                <div class=\"news_content\">
                    <p>".trimNewsContent($row[Content])."</p> 
                </div>
              </div>";
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: you'd need some code to detect when you are outputting the final post. quick/dirty way would be to get a row count, and see if you're outputting the final row. or fetch/cache into an array, then loop on the array, and you'll know then how big the array is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: [don't use `mysql_` functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12860046/5459839), but `mysqli_` or `PDO`. `mysql_` functions were deprecated several years ago and are no longer supported in the most recent versions of PHP.

There are several ways described in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12123933/php-check-mysql-last-row) on how to detect the last row of a result set.

I will not give a solution based on deprecated `mysql_` functions; you should first convert your code.

If you go for `mysqli_` and get a connection in *$con*, then you can do this:

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT NewsID, Title, Content, Author, date_format(Date, '%m/%d/%y') AS Date FROM news ORDER BY NewsID DESC LIMIT 2");
// fetch all rows
$rows = mysqli_fetch_all($query); // pass MYSQLI_ASSOC as 2nd argument if needed
foreach($rows as $i => $row) {
    $content = $i == count($rows)-1 ? $row['Content'] : trimNewsContent($row['Content']));
    echo ".... // etc
        $content
         ....// etc
    ";
}
```

If the goal is to treat the first record differently, then just change the condition accordingly:

```
    $content = $i == 0 ? $row['Content'] : trimNewsContent($row['Content']));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the assumption that latest is your first result which based on the query seems to be the case.

You need a conditional and a way to know when to trim so outside your while loop add:

```
$shouldTrim = false; //Sine the latest is your first item you do not want to trim first
```

Then at the top of your while loop

```
$content = "";
if($shouldTrim){//Anything but the latest
   $content = trimNewsContent($row[Content]);
} else { //This is your latest
   $content = $row[Content]; //output to full content
   $shouldTrim = true; //Set this to true going forward will trim
}
```

Now you can do

```
<p>".$content."</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's as Marc B and nerdlyist said. You need to know where is the last post. One way of doing it :

```
$query2 = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) AS nb_news FROM news");
$nbNews = mysql_fetch_array($query2);
```

With that you know how much news you have.

Before you while :

```
$i = 0;
```

Just after your while, increment $i : `$i++;`

Then test if $i is equal to the number of news, if so, you are at the last post:

```
if($i == $nbNews['nb_news'])
{
    $content = $row[Content];
}
else
{
    $content = trimNewsContent($row[Content]);
}
```